# Monitor and/or log the performance of a specific application (not all system) in Windows 7

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, performancecounter, perfmon

I need to keep track of peak memory usage, and average memory usage, CPU time of a specific application. I know there is Windows' **perfmon** tool, but it keeps record of all the system, but I need to keep record of just one specific application. I also tried **kiwimonitor** app, it does not provide precise result.

Do you know how to filter perform tool to just keep record of single application's performance statistics? Or is there a useful tool I can use for that purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a user defined data set (under Data Collector Sets) and limit your performance counters for a specific process. Once you select a process object, choose what process you want to monitor and the counters for that specific process.

Comment: That is very good. But It just allows selecting active processes, but the process I want to monitor can activate any time, then finish and then start again. So, whenever the process starts, I want to record its performance values. Thanks ...